# How can I specify region in `CodeBuildAction` in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am deploying a AWS codepiepline which includes cross region action in each stage. I am using CodebuildAction (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline-actions.CodeBuildAction.html)  inside stage of the pipeline and define all the build commands inside the action.

However, I can't see there is any parameter I can specify a region when create `CodebuildAction` instance. It is always run from the default region. How can I specify the region for `CodebuildAction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create the CodeBuild Project in another region, then import it with [`Project.fromProjectArn()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.Project.html#static-fromwbrprojectwbrarnscope-id-projectarn) when creating the action. The action's region is determined by the Project's region.